# Java Bean will create more than once

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, javabeans

I want to create a web calendar by using Enterprise Java Beans. So I program a class CalendarBean, that is stateful (@Stateful). As an attribute I use a deque to store all days. Alternatively I can add a new year at last or at first.
In a JSP I use the `<jsp:useBean>`-Tag. 
At each call of JSP, a new instance of the Bean will be created. Every time it creates a new deque.

How I can prevent it? I want just one instance of the Bean like a Singleton.

Comment: C'mon buddy, it's clear, it's STATEFUL, so it means it dependents to requests state, you need Stateless beans here :)

Answer (score 0):

In Stateful Session Bean, the instance variables represent the state of a unique client-bean session. So, each client will have its own instance. If you want instance of the Bean, you can use Statefull Session bean or Singleton Session bean.
U can see: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbly.html

Answer (score 0):

See the article [Contexts and Dependency Injection in Java EE 6](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/cdi-javaee-bien-225152.html). It says:

> A `@Stateful` bean is created by the container during the injection.

Hence, when your JSP is compiled an ran, the container will inject a new `CalenderBean`.

If you want your bean to be a singleton, best declare annotate it as `@Stateless`, and also *make* it stateless: its behaviour should not be dependent on the state of any instance variable. That means, if two threads would access the bean simultaneously, they should not be able to influence the way the bean behaves for each other by modifying instance variables.

For example, if your CalenderBean has an instance variable `private Calendar calendar`, and your instance method does something like this:

```
this.calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, input.getYear()); // where input is a parameter
                                                   // to the method you were calling
return calendar.get(Calendar.ERA);
```

Now imagine two visitors access your web page at the exact same instance, but they have different inputs:

- User 1 has `input.getYear()` is `2000`
- User 2 has `input.getYear()` is `-5`

As we cannot guarantee that the two threads will be handled sequentially, the following might happen:

- The thread that serves User 1 sets the year to `2000`
- The thread that serves User 2 sets the year to `-5`
- The thread that serves User 1 sets the ERA and returns `GregorianCalendar.BC`.

That is obviously wrong: user 1 has influenced the way the `CalendarBean` works for user 2, and this way, the bean is **not** stateless.

Comment: This means, the user should not be able to change the bean through calling methods in the JSP?

Comment: Stateless didn't give the effect I wish (see top comment) and if I use @Singleton, there happens nothing, too. Now I create a new Bean that has an instance variable of (own) Calendar, that is a singleton. So my list will produce once only. I have to use synchronized.. :(  - Could be the problem in scope of <jsp:useBean>? That I must to choose "session" instead of "request"?

Comment: The `scope` attribute of `<jsp:useBean>` only says something about where the bean may be found, or should be stored. If you use `session`, it means two consecutive HTTP requests will have the same instance, whereas `request` would imply every HTTP request (even in the same session) would have its own bean instance.

Comment: Ok, thank you. :) - My solution now: I didn't use <jsp:useBean> anymore, instead of I integrate a @EJB-reference into a servlet, that forwarding to the JSP. So I know, it is only one instance of Bean there.